# Restart a service on group hosts except on the host witch the playbook is running

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook where i update a cluster of 3 machines.
I use "serial: 1" to run one machine at a time.
And what I need is after each reboot I need to restart a list of services on other two machines.
How I can do that?

Sample of what I have:

```
- name: "Stop from booting and stop service"
    service:
      name: "{{item}}"
      enabled: no
      state: stopped
    loop: "{{service_list}}"
    when: standby.changed
    register: stop_service

##Reboot
  - name: "Reboot Server"
    reboot: 
      pre_reboot_delay: 120
      post_reboot_delay: 60
      reboot_timeout: 600
    when: stop_service.changed
    register: reboot_1

##Upgrade
  - name: "Upgrade SO"
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      upgrade: dist
    when: reboot_1.changed
    register: upgrade

##Reboot
  - name: "Reboot Server"
    reboot: 
      pre_reboot_delay: 60
      post_reboot_delay: 60
      reboot_timeout: 600
    when: upgrade.changed
    register: reboot_2

##Start Services
  - name: "Start service and enable start on booting"
    service:
      name: "{{item}}"
      state: started
      enabled: yes
    loop: "{{service_list}}"
    when: reboot_2.changed
    register: start_service

  - name: "Restart service on other machines"
    service:
      name: "{{item}}"
      state: restarted
    loop: "{{service_list}}"
    delegate_to: other machines....
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This won't scale well, and its not dynamic for shifting inventories, but for just a couple of servers you could do something like this, and just build one for each server that you are configuring:

```
 - name: "Restart service on other machines"
service:
  name: "{{item}}"
  state: restarted
loop: "{{service_list}}"
delegate_to: server1
when: inventory_hostname != 'server1'
```

Since you are running through them in a serial fashion already, when you are on server1, its conditional will fail, but it will pass for servers 2 and 3, and delegate that task to them.